# Does Orange Piccolo surpass Super Saiyan Blue?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

> In Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero, Piccolo gets a second transformation called Orange Piccolo. Supposedly his first transformation was unlocking his potential such as they did with Gohan, and for the performance he did it's said he could be around Gohan former to last's transformation, power unleashed Gohan. Now, power unleashed Gohan gave some fight to Goku Super Saiyan Blue, also, in the tournament of power he fought against Toppo and Dyspo alongside Freezer, who supposedly was at the level of Goku Super Saiyan Blue, so Gohan couldnt be so far of a super saiyan blue with his unleashed power form, which seems to be close to Piccolo's former to last transformation. Then, how about Piccolo's last transformation, Orange Piccolo?

Does Orange Piccolo surpass Super Saiyan Blue?